# Why do I get this message when I upload my aab file to publish my unity 3d game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

You have uploaded an APK file or Android App Bundle signed with a certificate that is not yet valid.

I've been trying to solve this in different ways for two weeks so I can publish my first game in google play console and I still haven't resuscitated it, if someone can help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need the certificate that you originally uploaded to Google and registered with them. Well, Google has two methods I believe one is providing them with a certificate (new method) and the old way was that they are checking to see that your newly uploaded file has the same certificate as the first AAB that you ever published. Either way, you should contact Google Play support and figure out how to register a new signing certificate.

Of course it's easier if you find the original private key file (used the first time you uploaded to Google Play) and put it back into your Unity Player settings and rebuild and try uploading again to see if it matches.

Answer (score 0):

Check your certificates are the same:

1. Google Play Console > Setup > App Integrity > Check Upload key certificate > SHA1
2. Unzip your .aab file.
3. Use your keytool to identify used SHA1 by your .aab-bundle
4. `keytool -printcert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA`

If they don't match, which is most likely the case, use the same keystore you used for the first time you uploaded your game to the google play console.

Unity > Edit > Project Settings > Player > Publishing Settings

If you don't have this keystore anymore, you need to either reset your keystore within Google Play Console, or create a new app with this console.

In more detail:
[developers.google.com...troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_the_certificate_fingerprint)